# Circular reference exception when serializing LINQ to SQL classes

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a set of linq to sql classes and serialized them into JSON using the .NET JavaScriptSerializer.

However, as soon as I add record onto a relating table, serialization throws a "Circular reference exception". Aaarggh!

It's described in detail [here](http://azamsharp.com/Posts/246_Fixing_the_JavaScriptSerializer_Circular_Reference_Exception.aspx).

I have a few options

- Convert the linq to sql class to a class with no relationships thus avoiding the circular reference
- snip the circular reference by nulling associations - i don't consider this to be a real option
- Use ScriptIgnoreAttribute (somehow). I couldn't easily apply this because the properties are in generated classes and LINQ to SQL doesn't automatically honor buddy classes
- Use JSON.NET and somehow use attributes + buddy classes to stop the serializer trying to walk across relationships.

Has anyone else encountered this? I would really prefer the last option if possible but I don't know how to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest version of Json.NET supports serializing circular relationships. Check out [Preserving Object References](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) in the help.

Comment: Wrote a blog post detailing the setup: http://www.johnnycode.com/blog/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/

Answer (score 4):

Additional link for accepted answer

[Json.NET Help, Preserving Object References (with example)](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/PreserveObjectReferences.html)

It seems it works fine with LINQ to SQL

Answer (score 1):

James's solution solved part of my problem.  I needed to exclude certain List Types within the object.  To solve my problem, I just copied the parts of the object I needed.  The following is an example.

```
var DB = new DBDataContext();
            var lUsers = new List<User>();
            DB.Users.ToList().ForEach(x => lUsers.Add(new User()
                {
                    ID = x.ID,
                    FIRST_NAME = x.FIRST_NAME
                }) );
```