# How do I avoid a circular reference while serializing Entity Framework class

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, objectquery

I have an MVC-3 (RC1) application using Entity Framework 4.

I wish to return a JSON object from a controller action. This object is referenced by other objects, which obviously return the reference.

I thus receive the following circular reference error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A circular reference was detected
>   while serializing an object of type
>   'Application.Models.ReferenceObject'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: A
>   circular reference was detected while
>   serializing an object of type
>   'Application.Models.ReferenceObject'.

NB: **Application** & **ReferenceObject** are obviously replacements for the actual namespace / object.

According to [Stack Overflow: Circular reference exception when serializing LINQ to SQL classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468584/circular-reference-exception-when-serializing-linq-to-sql-classes), this can be overcome using JSON.Net; however I would like to avoid this and instead try to exclude the offending reference properties from the object being serialized.

What do I mean?

I want to do something like this:

```
IList<ReferenceObject> list = Repository.GetReferenceObjects();
return Json(list.**<method>**("ObjectsReferencingThis"));
```

where `**<method>**` is some method that does the opposite to the [`ObjectQuery(Of T).Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) method and `ObjectsReferencingThis` is the property that is causing the circular reference.

**NB:** I do not wish to remove these properties or create POCOs as this only affects the Json serialization.

Anyone able to help please?

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem when worked on one of my previous project.
Here is what I ended up doing:

```
IList<Product> list = Repository.GetProducts();
  var collection = products.Select(product => new
        {
            id = product.Id,
            name = product.Name,
            detailUrl = product.DetailUrl,
            imageLargeUrl = product.ThumbNailUrl,
            tagtitle = product.Name.ToUpper(),
            tagheader = "Words our cherished patrons use to describe this product",
            tagwords = from tag in product.Tags group tag by tag.Name into words select new { name =          words.Key, weight = words.Count() }
        });

 var result = new {id = inquiry.Id, products = collection, };
 return this.Jsonp(result);
```

Here is how the result Json would look like:

```
{
"id" : 2,
"products" : [{
    "id" : "3605970008857",
    "name" : "TITLE1",
    "detailUrl" : "http://www.urlhere.com",
    "tagwords" : [{
        "name" : "roses",
        "weight" : 1
    },
    {
        "name" : "cotton",
        "weight" : 1
    },
    {
        "name" : "happy",
        "weight" : 1
    }]
},
{
    "id" : "3605970019891",
    "name" : "TITLE2",
    "detailUrl" : "http://www.urlhere.com",
    "tagwords" : []
}],
```

}

You can also add any other properties from you referenced objects to the result as you wish,to be shown in your Json object :)

Comment: Hi @laurvasile, yep, this was the method that I am using as a "workaround" as well. I'm not 100% happy with it though as it is not exactly dynamic... any changes to the Model then need to be reflected into this manual JSON conversion. I think it would be far more efficient if you could just exclude a field / property / reference as part of the LINQ query, similar to the INCLUDE function.

Comment: accepted as answer (although its actually a "workaround" imho)

Answer (score 0):

I made a very trivial solution which is not recommended if you have very big list

```
letters=UserOperations.GetDepartmentLettersForSecretary(pageNumber, pageSize,(Session["User"] as User).DepartmentID.Value, (Session["User"] as User).ID);

foreach (Letter letter in letters)
{
    letter.LetterStatus.Letters = null;
}
```

the problem of `circular reference` in my case is in LetterStatus.Letters 
so I `Iterated through the list` and `assigned it to null`

as I told you its `not recommended` if you have `very big list`