# How to Get Full Object with Code First Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, code-first, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to return as JSON the fully deep object (with all of the foreign key relationships filled in) but I am getting nulls for all the referenced objects.

Here is the call to get the object:

```
    public ActionResult GetAll()
    {
        return Json(ppEFContext.Orders, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And here is the Order object itself:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Patient Patient { get; set; }

    public CertificationPeriod CertificationPeriod { get; set; }

    public Agency Agency { get; set; }

    public Diagnosis PrimaryDiagnosis { get; set; }

    public OrderApprovalStatus ApprovalStatus { get; set; }

    public User Approver { get; set; }

    public User Submitter { get; set; }

    public DateTime ApprovalDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsDeprecated { get; set; }
}
```

I have not yet found a good resource on using EF 4.1 Annotations. If you could suggest a good one, that has the answer, you could give me the link and that would be enough of an answer for me!

Regards,

Guido

> **Update**
>
> I added the virtual keyword as per Saxman and am now
>   dealing with the circular reference
>   error issue.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251794/how-to-have-many-to-many-association-in-entity-framework-code-first what type of an Enumerable is the OrderApprovalStatus etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `virtual` keyword before your related entities:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }

    public virtual CertificationPeriod CertificationPeriod { get; set; }

    public virtual Agency Agency { get; set; }

    public virtual Diagnosis PrimaryDiagnosis { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderApprovalStatus ApprovalStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual User Approver { get; set; }

    public virtual User Submitter { get; set; }

    public DateTime ApprovalDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsDeprecated { get; set; }
}
```

You might end up with a `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object...` error if your objects have references of each other. In that case, you will need to create a `ViewModel` or something similar to overcome this problem. Or use LINQ to project an anonymous object.

Comment: This made progress, but now I am where you describe. With a circular reference exception. I am reading about adding the id of the foreign object to the model and other solutions as well.

Comment: You can't really do much about it at the moment, serializing with an object referencing another object is not possible. Like I've suggested, you could create a ViewModel that only have the data you needed, or project to an anonymous object, i.e: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436328/how-do-i-avoid-a-circular-reference-while-serializing-entity-framework-class

Answer (score 2):

Read about [Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx)

Comment: My first thought was to look at lazy loading.

Comment: Yes, but if you always need to load every referenced property, explicitly writing Include with every load isn't comfortable, maybe there's another way to configure lazy loading